# Radio buttons are not working

Tags: jsp

After wring the below code, all radio buttons are selecting rather than one. Can anybody help me.

```
<form action="" method="post">    
<input type="radio" name="discover" value="male">Discover     
<input type="radio" name="capital" value="capital">Capital One
<input type="radio" name="dcu" value="dcu">DCU  
<input type="radio" name="debit" value="debit">Debit Card<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: If you want radio buttons to behave as a group, you must give them all the same name: the value of the `name` attribute must be the same. The `id` attributes can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **name** setting tells which group of radio buttons the field belongs to. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.
If you couldn't define which group the current button belongs to, you could only have one group of radio buttons on each page.

Make changes as below, **name** has been made common as "`card`", to make it as a `group`.

```
<input type="radio" name="card" value="male">Discover     
<input type="radio" name="card" value="capital">Capital One
<input type="radio" name="card" value="dcu">DCU  
<input type="radio" name="card" value="debit">Debit Card<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: @Munni please upvote/accept the answer if it solves your purpose.